# c# Web Api with CORS Enabled and the dreaded No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a C# Web API project. I created a Controller using the Web API 2 standard. I am trying to enable CORS on only one action, this is what I have:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class MyControllerController : ApiController
    {
        // POST api/mycontroller
        [EnableCors("http://link.myurl.com", "*", "*")]
        public bool Post(MyCustomObject customObject)
        {
            // Function that returns Bool
            return myFunction(customObject);
        }
    }
}
```

My WebApiConfig.cs looks like this:

```
// Web API configuration and services
config.EnableCors(); 

// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

// Ignore Null values on JSON Returns
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore };
```

Here is the Cross-Domain AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://myurl.com/api/mycontroller',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Type: 'TextHere', OtherInfo: 'TextHere' }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Based off tutorials such as this one: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#how-it-works, I should have everything properly setup.

I continue to get the following error in Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl.com/api/mycontroller. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://link.myurl.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

When I take a look at the calls using Fiddler, I notice that the Pre-flight Origin check goes through fine with Status 200, but when the actual call is made it returns 500.

**Interestingly enough, the transactions are committed to the database even though the call failed. It's almost like the Pre-flight Origin check is running through the code when it should just be checking for Allow Origin.**

I've tried adding the following to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://link.myurl.com" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 <system.webServer>
```

If I leave the [EnableCors] line, then I get an error that two values are specified (http://link.myurl.com) when there can only be one. If I remove the [EnabledCors] line, I get the original error.

If you can't already tell, I'm at a loss here. Ironically it is working (database actions being committed), but the browser thinks its not working and never accepts the JSON return data.

HELP?

Comment: Have you tried to replace "http://link.myurl.com" with "*" in [EnableCors(...)] just for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked this time around, but I got it working. The main difference might be the library I installed using NuGet:

**Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Cross-Origin Support**

I then set the WebApiConfig.cs file as specified in my initial post, as well as the EnableCors option above the Action I wanted to allow it on.

I did NOT set anything in the web.config file.

I no longer receive the error, must have something to do with the NuGet package.

Answer (score 1):

I got caught out by this. You have to `EnableCORS` after the routes attribute have been mapped if using Attribute routing.

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

// Web API configuration and services
config.EnableCors();
```