# CORS Error when trying to return an Object from asp.net Web API 2 to Angular Front end

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

So I have two projects, one is the asp.net Web API2 and the other is the Angular 1.5 Client side. I'm starting pretty simple, just returning a list of objects but when I try this I always get the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` which is very confusing to me since if I return a list of strings I do not get this error and the data loads fine.
Here is my angular call:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:53574/api/ReturnStringList")
    .then(function(response) {
    //success
    console.log(response.data);
    angular.copy(response.data, vm.links);
    }, function (error) {
    //failure
    vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load data";
    });
```

Web API Controller Methods

```
// GET api/DataController
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    var stringList= db.Links.Take(10).Select(x => x.LinkString).ToList();
    return stringList;
}
// GET api/DataController/5
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Link> Get(string id)
{
    var links = db.Links.Take(10).ToList();

    return links;
}
```

My Web API's config file: `WebApiConfig`

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services


        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
```

So if I change the get URL to be `api/ReturnStringList` it'll return the list of strings fine but it i then go to `api/ReturnStringList/5` it will return the error below without me changing anything else.

[image]

I've inspected the Response and I can see that the header is not there on the failed case but is clearly there on the succeeding one, yet I do not understand why this is happening.

**Edit**: I've looked through the other topic suggested by @Jim G but did not solve it. I am using that NuGet Package suggested and I have adjusted my config ordering as noticed without change

**Update: ** I found that there was something going wrong on the server, after working with fiddler for a bit I found that the object wasn't being serialized properly. After adding `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;` it's working fine

Comment: The error is probably something configuration related. How is your routing set up? Can you see errors on the server?

Comment: @Irb I got it set up pretty simple, I've added the whole Register method to the question, apart from that I don't have any filters or other config for the Api, that method is the only thing called in `Global.asax`. As for errors I dont see any errors. The controller method runs through fine from the break point's i've put on it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Web Api with CORS Enabled and the dreaded No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675172/c-sharp-web-api-with-cors-enabled-and-the-dreaded-no-access-control-allow-origi)

Answer (score 1):

Believe you need to add the OPTIONS method to your CorsEnableAttribute.

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
```

You'll note an Options call goes out before the Get request to do some pre-flight sniffing. If you don't support the method, the CORS can't work. From Mozilla's [write up on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

> the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request,
>   soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS
>   request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the
>   actual request with the actual HTTP request method.